# How to manipulate file thread-safely in Java?

Tags: thread-safety, file-access

Every time a page is requested on my website, I log some details with a service call like this:

```
logService.logPageRequest(session, request, contentId);
```

This service call makes use of a static FileUtils (my own) method to do the actual update on the file.

```
public static void appendToTextFile(String string, String fileRootDirectory, String subdirectory, String filename, boolean startOnNewLine) throws Exception {
    // code irrelevant to the question removed

    String filePath=fileDirectory+"/"+filename;
    File file=new File(filePath);
    if(file.exists()) {
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter(filePath, true);
        if(startOnNewLine) {
            out.write("\r\n");
        }
        out.write(string);
        out.close();
     } else {
         FileWriter out = new FileWriter(filePath);
         out.write(string);
         out.close();
}
```

Every so often (let's say scheduled every 15 minutes), I execute another service which renames this file and starts processing it.

I'd like to understand how I can go about ensuring that both concurrent writes are safe and rename is not executed while a write is in the process. I guess the answer will be some form of synchronization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two services need to share a *synchronization object*: it can be anything (even `new byte[1]`) but it must be the one and same instance, passed into your "services". Whenever there is a *critical section*, which means part of a code which wants to operate on a *shared resource*, it needs to be wrapped in

```
synchronized(theInstanceOfSynchronizationObject) {
  // ... your code for critical section
}
```

The rule of good locking is to know deterministically what are you locking, what is exactly the shared resource. What will kill you (and introduce deadlocks) is random adding of synchronized blocks in hope of "solving". In your particular example, it's most probably the actions on `file`: *just actions*, not the operations on filename strings, neither the instantiation of `File` : you can have many `File` objects pointing to the same *file on disk* and it's not a critical operation, as long as it does not touch the disk yet. So i would say

```
File file=new File(filePath);
synchronized(theInstanceOfSynchronizationObject) {
  if(file.exists()) {
  } else {
  }
}
```

Similarly, protect the `File` *actions* in your other service. Keep in mind that it's not `File` object you are protecting, but *the file itself*.

Comment: Pavel, what would theInstanceOfSynchronizationObject be? Some kind of public static Object property somewhere? You create a separate dedicated class for those? What about the performance hit. Every time we write to the file, we need to synchronize. I wonder what this means in practice. Some people choose to write to a queue rather than directly to the file. Have you done any of this and know enough to choose what makes sense?

Comment: public static property is the simplest way, though somewhat dirty. Cleaner is to have a special instance being passed into the services (via constructor perhaps). Dedicated class is not necessary, you just need to use `Object` (any Object) ability to act as lock. While locking takes some time indeed, it is still several orders of magnitude faster than accessing a disk file. So i won't consider it performance problem.